# How to remove old DocSets from Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I have an old Xcode 4 DocSet that I can't seem to figure out how to remove. It's not showing up in my DocSets folder in Finder. Does anyone know how I can remove this from Xcode? I've tried removing the Xcode.docset in finder, but all this does is remove my Xcode 7.3 documentation, it does not remove the Xcode 4 documentation. Thank you!

[Xcode Documents View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wb6Q.png)

[Finder Documents View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnHkh.png)